# Change color of HTML <option> Tag using id element after being clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, interactive

I tried to find a solution for this but i haven't found what i want.
this is an example :

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
```

for example after clicking "Ford" option" it's color transforms to red .        Am new to Jquery, and what i want to know is if that possible in the first place and if it is , then how ?
Note that am targetting a single value, after condition is met. So what i wanna know is syntax that will change the color of the element related to some id (AFTER THE SELECT MENU CLOSES) if possible.

THANKS IN ADVANCE .

Comment: What should happen with Ford, when next you click on the BMW ?

Comment: what i wanna know is how , to interactively change a single value on condition met . I mean its only related to a single value if possible.

Comment: @ellipsis thanks a lot for your help that's the answer i were looking for

Comment: @bilelboulares happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find to find the `selected` `option` `onchange` and apply color using `.css`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option').css('background-color', 'white');
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
  </select>
</div>
```